# MySQL: an efficient binary value comparison

Tags: mysql, types, binary

My table has 8 VARCHAR fields of binary strings of 64bits each one. My goal is to get  [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) for each register. I was doing it with the next query :

```
SELECT 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str0, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000001101111000000000101011100000000001010100000000001111101', 2, 10 )) + 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str1, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000010110001000000001000000000000000011000010000000011110100', 2, 10 )) + 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str2, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000010010100000000000010101100000000110001000000000011100100', 2, 10 )) + 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str3, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000011101011000000000001110000000000101100010000000000011001', 2, 10 )) + 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str4, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000000010000000000000011010100000000111011100000000001001101', 2, 10 )) + 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str5, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000000101111000000000110101000000000000010100000000000101101', 2, 10 )) + 
 BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str6, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000000011000000000000101011000000000001010000000000000001011', 2, 10 )) + 
BIT_COUNT(CONV(fp.bin_str7, 2, 10 ) ^ CONV('0000000000101011000000000011100100000000000100000000000000111010', 2, 10 )) from mytable fp
```

So this query is extremely slow. There are some reasons: mytable has 3M registers and the field `fp.bin_stri` is of VARCHAR type.

*As MySQL has BINARY type, can I execute the same query over `fp.bin_stri` of BINARY type? An how?*

I'm confused because, when I have changed `fp.bin_stri` to BINARY, the data of this field has appeared as BLOB and now I don't know how the query should look like. Should it use `CONV`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 64-bit binary string is the same size as MySQL's `BIGINT` type (standard size on modern hardware of double-precision float or long integer). Use a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` to store each field, then you can compare to other bit fields using the `b'1010...'` syntax instead of `CONV()`.

```
BIT_COUNT(fp.strN ^ b'0000000001101111000000000101011100000000001010100000000001111101')
```

Should be really fast since the hardware is designed to do bit ops on 64-bit values.

Comment: And when I insert to database a new value, how should I cast it? Is it enough to insert it as BINARY?

Comment: If you are inserting sequences of 1's and 0's, you can use the binary literal syntax "b'<binary_digits>'". `INSERT INTO mytable (str1,...) VALUES (b'1010',...)`.

Comment: I should add that `LOAD DATA INFILE` will be much faster for loading the whole table if you need to do it frequently, but you need to represent the binary fields as unsigned integers in the file. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html.